# How to get azure queue names using namespace endpoint?

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

Is there any way to get all the Microsoft-Azure service bus queues name using crated namespace endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Using namespaceManager we can get all the queue's name.

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);           

//Getting all available queue's.
IEnumerable<QueueDescription> queueList = namespaceManager.GetQueues();

foreach (QueueDescription qd in queueList)
{
Console.WriteLine("Queue name {0}", qd.Path, qd.MessageCount);
}
```